# How to maintain maximum number of records in a table. Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have the following problem, I have a table with a foreign key and a creation date column.

At the time a new record is inserted, I need to check how many records exist with the same foreign key, and if the query throws more than N records, I have to delete the oldest record. So that there are always only N records of the same foreign key.

I could do it from the application, (I'm doing a REST API) but I do not think it's optimal, and I'd rather do it with a Trigger directly in SQL.

For example

```
+----+----------+------------+
|       TABLE: example       |
+----+----------+------------+
| FK | DATE.... | MORE_FIELD |
+----+----------+------------+
| 01 | 17/12/92 |            |
| 01 | 17/12/93 |            |
| 02 | 17/12/92 |            |
| 01 | 17/12/94 |            |
| 02 | 17/12/93 |            |
| 03 | 17/12/92 |            |
+----+----------+------------+
```

```
INSERT INTO example(FK, DATE, MORE_FIELD) VALUES(01,now(), "...");
```

After insert on example

```
IF (SELECT count(FK) FROM example WHERE new.FK = example.FK > N) 
THEN DELETE THE OLDEST RECORD;
```

If new.FK = 1 and N = 3 then the register (01 | 17/12/92) should be removed after insertion

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20145/possible-to-keep-max-number-of-records-in-postgresql

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon That solution is flawed - if two `INSERT`s are running concurrently, you can easily end up with one more record than the limit, because the `SELECT`s in the concurrent triggers don't see the uncommitted `INSERT` by the other transaction. You'd have to use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions to make this work reliably.